# SQL Comparing two attributes as 1 combination

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am student, new to database programming and new to Stack Overflow!

Basically I have a database which has:

Table => Attributes

```
Mine => MineID, Name, NumberOfWorkers
Ore => OreID, Name, ChemicalFormula                 
OreProduction => OreProdID, Mine, Ore, AmountPerYear
Contract = > ContractID, Ore, Mine, Smelter, AmountOfOre
```

There are other tables but I think these are those relevant to my problem.

Now my Question is :

"Which mines have the capacity to mine an ore that they have not yet contracted to a smelter, and
what Ore(s) are they?"

Now this gives me all the mines that can mine an ore AND have it is contracted to a smelter

```
SELECT DISTINCT Mine.Name, Ore.Name
FROM OreProduction
INNER JOIN Mine
ON Mine.MineID = OreProduction.Mine
INNER JOIN Ore
ON Ore.OreID = OreProduction.Ore
INNER JOIN ContractDetail
ON OreProduction.Mine = ContractDetail.Mine
AND OreProduction.Ore = ContractDetail.Ore
```

How can I get the inverse for this ? 
I've tried to use this as a sub query but how can I tell SQL that Mine and Ore together NOT IN the above sub query ?

I hope you've understood what I'm trying to say and thanks in advance for your replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a LEFT JOIN and use a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Mine.Name, Ore.Name
FROM OreProduction
INNER JOIN Mine
ON Mine.MineID = OreProduction.Mine
INNER JOIN Ore
ON Ore.OreID = OreProduction.Ore
LEFT JOIN ContractDetail
ON OreProduction.Mine = ContractDetail.Mine
AND OreProduction.Ore = ContractDetail.Ore
WHERE Contract.Mine is null
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys it worked :). I've been trying to use the left join but didn't include the where clause and no data was being returned. Thanks A lot!

Answer (score 1):

An INNER JOIN will only return rows that meet the join conditions, and leave out any rows from either table that don't match.

A LEFT or RIGHT join will return *all* the data from one table (the left or right), and matching data from the other table.  If there are no rows that match, then the columns are NULL in the output.

So, a hint would be:   try doing a LEFT OUTER JOIN from Ore to ContractDetail, and then filtering the result of that with a WHERE clause that looks specifically for "null" in the contract details.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys it worked :). I've been trying to use the left join but didn't include the where clause and no data was being returned. Thanks A lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) to get the rows from `OreProduction` table not already in `ContractDetail` table.

```
select Mine, Ore
from OreProduction
except
select Mine, Ore
from ContractDetail
```

Put that in a sub query and join the result back to `Ore` and `Mine` to get the names.

```
select 
  M.Name,
  O.Name
from  
  (select Mine, Ore
   from OreProduction
   except
   select Mine, Ore
   from ContractDetail) as P
  inner join Mine as M
    on M.MineID = P.Mine
  inner join Ore as O
    on O.OreID = P.Ore
```

Comment: Actually this is what I was thinking of at first. When I asked the question. Thanks, now I've got another sql keyword in my arsenal :)